# Continuous Time count For data is out of band-

Tags: r, excel, tableau-api

I have frequency data (interval -1 minute). I would like to count the continuous time for which data is out of band(band- 49 to 51). I don't want the total time. I need continuous time it may occur on different time. Assume for a day on 6 PM frequency samples are 48.3 48.2,48.7,49.1. The result should be 3 minutes. Using R or Excel, how can I do it?

Comment: Doesn't it depend on what window you apply? Also can you show us how the data is laid out and say what you've tried.

Comment: I am not finding any way that counts the continuous time..i tried to use if condition for true it prompted 1.other wise zero. Finally I count total no of 1 ..but I don't need this .I want that frequency goes high for 7 min at 4pm and for 9 min at 7 pm...I will not get this type of solution by my ways ,I am power system engineer. I use R not frequent user of excel function . this is necessary for us to operate grid ..please suggest I have two column in first column time sample in one minute. second column has frequency

Answer (score 1):

In Tableau, you can use a table calculation that runs along the time dimension.

For example, define a calculated field called **in_band** as

```
[Frequency] >= 49 and [Frequency] <= 51
```

and then a calculated field called **current_minutes_out_of_band** as

```
if attr(in_band) then 0 else previous_value(0) + 1 end
```

If you put MINUTE(TIME) on the Rows shelf and make it discrete, you can place current_minutes_out_of_band on the Text shelf and watch the counter accumulate minutes out of band.

This expression resets the counter back to zero whenever the frequency returns to the desired band. If you want a running total, that is even easier -- just define a field that returns 1 if in_band and 0 otherwise. Place that field on a shelf, right click on it and choose quick Table Calc running total

This assumes one data row per minute with no gaps. It could be generalized to avoid those assumptions.

Table calcs are computed on the client side of the client/server divide, so require fetching each row of times and frequencies across the wire. For large data sets, it is usually more efficient to do the computation at the data source and send back only aggregate results. SQL windowing functions, or Oracle analytical functions can do that.

Table calcs also depend on setting the addressing and partitioning correctly. See the docs on table calcs for details.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you can do it using an array formula to search for the next frequency which is in range:-

```
=MATCH(1,(B2:B$10>=49)*(B2:B$10<=51),0)-1
```

if your frequencies start in B2.

Must be entered in C2 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Here is a modified version which allows for the case where the last frequency is out of range, assuming there are no blanks between frequency values and one or more blanks at the end:-

```
=MATCH(1,(B2:B$10>=49)*(B2:B$10<=51)+(B2:B$10=""),0)-1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done elegantly in R using the `rle` function, which computes the run-length encoding of data. Consider some sample input:

```
times <- paste0("18:0", 0:8)
freq <- c(48.3, 48.2, 48.7, 49.1, 50, 51.1, 51.2, 52, 50)
```

We can determine the length of the times out of band (2 segments of 3 minutes each) using `rle`:

```
with(rle(freq < 49 | freq > 51), lengths[values])
# [1] 3 3
```

We can also determine the times at which these runs ended:

```
with(rle(freq < 49 | freq > 51), times[cumsum(lengths)][values])
# [1] "18:02" "18:07"
```

Comment: Thanks It is working .it is so simple and useful.it will help us to maintain frequency.Can i also see  the time stamp  with the corresponding frequency(that is crossing the upper bound)..it would be more useful..by using this i can say" at 1800 hr frequency was out of bound for 3 mins"

Comment: @rahul I've updated to include code to compute when these runs end

Comment: Thanks a lot ,earlier I thought r was only suited to data visualisation,but it do more what excel macro do.i think for excel macro for transferring data from one to other location R can also do it in more efficient way